# Let $E$ be a reflexive Banach space and $M$ its closed linear subspace. Then $M$ is reflexive

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, reflexive-space

I'm trying to re-phrase this proof in Brezis's book of Functional Analysis.

> Let $E$ be a reflexive Banach space and $M$ its closed linear subspace. Then $M$ is reflexive.

Could you have a check if I understand and apply concept of compactness/subspace topology correctly?

*PS:* I posted my proof separately so that I can accept my own answer to remove my question from unanswered list. Surely, if other people post answers, then I will happily accept theirs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Kakutani's theorem, $M$ is reflexive if and only if $B_M := \{x\in M | |x| \le 1\}$ is compact in the weak topology $\sigma(M, M')$. Notice that $\sigma(M, M')$ [coincides](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4380358/sigmam-m-coincides-with-the-subspace-topology-that-sigmae-e-induce) with the subspace topology that $\sigma(E, E')$ induces on $M$. So $M$ is reflexive *if and only if* $B_M$ is compact in $\sigma(E, E')$.

Also by Kakutani's theorem, we have $B_E$ is compact in $\sigma(E,E')$. A closed subset of a compact set is also compact, so it suffices to show that $B_M$ is closed in $B_E$ w.r.t. $\sigma(E, E')$. This is indeed true because $B_M = M \cap B_E$ where $M$ is convex and closed in norm topology, and thus closed in $\sigma(E, E')$.